# Docbook-XSL remove page break after part

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I'm generating a PDF from a DocBook XML, styling it with an XSL stylesheet, using FOP as processing tool.

Is it possible to remove the page break after the title of a part element ?

Thanks,

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using Apache-FOP to do the pdf-rendering for you. Apache-FOP rendering is about interpreting the XSL-FO tags and rendering them to matching pdf-elements.
The answer to your question is in the generation of the XSL-FO for which you say you use XSLT. Check what the XSLT does with a 'title of a part element' and change it to your liking.

Good luck with your project, 
Wim